# Numbers 18 states that Levites have No inheritance among the sons of Israel, but Deuteronomy 18 says Levites could sell their estates

Tags: law, numbers, deuteronomy, leviticus

> Numbers 18:23-24 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>    23 Only the
>   **Levites** shall perform the service of the tent of meeting, and they
>   shall bear their iniquity; it shall be a perpetual statute throughout
>   your generations, and among the sons of Israel they shall have no
>   inheritance. 24 For the tithe of the sons of Israel, which they offer
>   as an offering to the Lord, I have given to the Levites for an
>   inheritance; therefore I have said concerning them, **‘They shall have
>   no inheritance among the sons of Israel.’”**

In the verse above, it states  that the Levites shall have No inheritance among the sons of Israel ( correct me if I'm wrong, I believe it also means the Levites can Not own land ).

> Deuteronomy 18 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>   6 “Now if a Levite
>   comes from any of your [e]towns throughout Israel where he resides,
>   and comes [f]whenever he desires to the place which the Lord chooses,
>   7 then he shall serve in the name of the Lord his God, like all his
>   fellow Levites who stand there before the Lord. 8 They shall eat
>   [g]equal portions, except what they receive from the **sale of their
>   fathers’ estates.**

Therefore, how could the Levites have any estates that is mentioned in Deuteronomy 18?

Answer (score 2):

*When Joshua led the Israelites into the land of Canaan the Levites were the only Israelite tribe that received cities but were not allowed to be landowners because "the Lord God of Israel is their inheritance, as he said to them.*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribe_of_Levito

I think the best answer is that they were not allowed to be landowners - meaning farmers - but nevertheless Levites could own their homes and houses in the city. I can't be certain of this however.

*The Levites always have the right to redeem their houses in the Levitical towns, which they possess.* Leviticus 25:32

Answer (score 1):

KJV - Lev. 25:32-34

32 Notwithstanding the cities of the Levites, and the houses of the cities of their possession, may the Levites redeem at any time.

33 And if a man purchase of the Levites, then the house that was sold, and the city of his possession, shall go out in the year of jubile: **for the houses of the cities of the Levites are their possession among the children of Israel.**

34 But the field of the suburbs of their cities may not be sold; for it is their perpetual possession.